# Obtener el mes del año segun el dia introducido

Tags: java

como puedo obtener el mes del año segun el dia introducido

si pongo dia : 5
es Enero

si pongo dia 35 pertence a Febrero Y así etc.

Answer (score -1):

Podés usar el objeto [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) para parsear una fecha a partir de la cantidad de días que han transcurrido, usando el patrón `D yyyy` para parsear el día según el número ingresado y el año corriente:

```
Date fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("D yyyy").parse(numeroDia + " " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
calendario.setTime(fecha);

String[] meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Novimebre', 'Diciembre'];
System.out.putLine('El dia ' + numeroDia + ' corresponde al mes de ' + meses[calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
```